# Is there a way to restrict the driving directions in google map to a certain polygon area?

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to restrict the driving directions to a certain specific city or say any area marked in a polygon field? If so how do you restrict the user from adding markers on the map only to a confined area?

Answer (score 0):

**No it's not possible unless you have your own ArcGIS server.**

Using the API this isn't possible. 
There was a discussion a while ago that suggested this be added as a feature request.

This then led to a discussion and feature request enhancement but it's still only in the "Acknowledged" status. So it's not possible at the moment

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214

If you have an ArcGIS server you can do this yourself.... but not with the native GMaps 3 API.

For example see this page: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/arcgislink/examples/routebarriers.html

You can set up road blocks were routing directions will avoid. But these **are not polygons** as you require.

### Without Roadblock

[image]

### With Roadblock

[image]